# Cycle error in Terraform when combining ELB and Auto Scaling Group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, terraform

I want to create an ASG with only 1 instance initially.

I want all the instances of this ASG to be behind an ELB.

So I set `load_balancers = ["${aws_elb.Production-Web-ELB.name}"]` in the `resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "ProductionWeb-ScalingGroup"` .

Now, when I write the code for the `resource "aws_elb" "Production-Web-ELB"`, and I set `instances = ["${aws_autoscaling_group.ProductionWeb-ScalingGroup.*.id}"]`, I get the error...

```
Error configuring: 1 error(s) occurred:

* Cycle: aws_autoscaling_group.ProductionWeb-ScalingGroup, aws_elb.Production-Web-ELB
```

I understand that this error means that the one resource references the other in a circle. To check it I comment out the `load_balancers = ["${aws_elb.Production-Web-ELB.name}"]` part and `terraform plan` without any error.

So my question is: Am I unable using Terraform to create an ASG with an attached ELB and every EC2 that will spawn inside it will be automatically behind the ELB ?

Is there something from the documentation that I missed?

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly define the instances that will be associated with the ELB in terraform's ELB definition. By using the [load_balancers](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/autoscaling_group.html#load_balancers) argument, you're associating the ELB with the AutoScaling group, and AutoScaling will know to attach any instances that are created to that ELB when the AutoScaling group launches that instance.

Terraform isn't directly managing the state of the instances in this case -- AWS AutoScaling is, so their state likewise don't need to be defined in terraform beyond defining a launch configuration and associating it to the AutoScaling group.

To tell terraform to launch the AutoScaling group with a single instance, set your [min_size](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/autoscaling_group.html#min_size) argument to 1 and let your scaling policies handle the desired capacity from there.  You could alternatively set [desired_capacity](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/autoscaling_group.html#desired_capacity) to 1, but be wary of managing that state in terraform because it will set the desired_capacity to 1 every time you apply your plan.

Comment: Thank you Anthony. That makes sense. 'terraform plan' does not produce any errors. I'll confirm it with 'apply' in the following days .